# Attach a div next to button in componentDidMount - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to attach a info icon div next to a button node when the page loads.
I am trying to do that in the componentDidMount but the button node is not available till that time.

I am trying a setTimeout but it depends on the data in the table sometimes it works using 3000ms but sometimes if the data is more it doesnt appear.

Is there any better/sure shot way of attaching the info node.

The button node is coming from a external lib I am using so I am not creating that node in the render/return method so cant add that time.

```
    componentDidMount() {

        window.setTimeout(() => {
            const actionSectionnode = document.querySelector('#main-content .action-section');
            const template = `<div style="padding-top: 10px">
            <i class="icon-info-tip-filled"
                    title="abcdefghijk......"
                ></i>
            </dnx-tooltip>`;
            if ($(actionSectionnode).length > 0) {
                actionSectionnode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', template);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

One more thing - The button node is coming when I am using a query selector but doesnt appear when document.getElementsByClassName is used. As the queryselector is dangerous - what else can I use.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using pure javascript, what you could do is [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

You should have a state that says if you should render the div

```
state = {
    ...
    isDivShowing = false;
}
```

In `componentDidMount` you set the state to `true`

```
componentDidMount(){
    ...
    this.setState({isDivShowing: true})
    ...
}
```

And in render, you check it before rendering

```
render() {
    return(
        ...
        {   // conditional rendering 
            this.state.isDivShowing && ( 
                <div>...</div>
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned. I am not displaying the action-section div. it is a part of table( external library) and i have no access to it in the render. Is there any other way to add node. Is there any callback I can add which checks when the div is available add this node?